# Unable To Parse JSON Response in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to parse a whois json response but when I try parse it I get null values.

```
string html;
string whoisUrl = "https://whois.apitruck.com/:google.com";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(whoisUrl);
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
Class1 m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(html);
MessageBox.Show(m.created);
```

Object

```
class Class1
{
    public string created { get; set; }
}
```

can anyone please point what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: show json data and error

Comment: @Backs i am not able to format the json into the question but here is json url https://whois.apitruck.com/:google.com and there is no error just when i try to use "created" element it gives a null value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Class1` doesn't get the value since "created" is part of the "response" and not the root level of the JSON reponse.

You'll either need to use `dynamic` or create a hierarchy for the classes for a simple fix.

```
class Class1
{
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

class Response
{
    public string created { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use this:

```
Class1 m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(html);
MessageBox.Show(m.Response.created);
```

**UPDATE**

Also, here's an example of how to use the `dynamic`:

```
var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(html);
DateTime created = (DateTime)m.response.created;
```

Comment: Added example of how to use `dynamic` as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is nice [app](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert json to .net class:

```
public class Registrar
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object email { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string idnName { get; set; }
    public List<string> status { get; set; }
    public List<string> nameserver { get; set; }
    public object ips { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string changed { get; set; }
    public string expires { get; set; }
    public bool registered { get; set; }
    public bool dnssec { get; set; }
    public string whoisserver { get; set; }
    public List<object> contacts { get; set; }
    public Registrar registrar { get; set; }
    public List<string> rawdata { get; set; }
    public object network { get; set; }
    public object exception { get; set; }
    public bool parsedContacts { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int error { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

...

RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(html);
var created = result.response.created;
```